# Type 'Promise<any>' is missing the following properties angular

Tags: typescript, http, angular7

I am making the http connection to my system in angular7. But, it is giving error in the module. This message appears when I created the get request:

```
Type 'Promise<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, user, email
```

Module:

```
export class User { 
  id: number
  user: string
  email: string
}
```

Request:

```
users: User;

    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
          response => {
            if (!response) {
              console.log(Error)
            } else {
              this.users = response
            }
          })
```

Http Get:

```
getUsers() {
        return this.service.get(this.endpoint)
        .map((response) => {
            return response;
        });
    }
```

service:

```
standardHeaders() {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        if (this.authToken) {
            headers.append('X-Authorization', this.authToken);
        }
        return { headers: headers };
    }

 get(path: string) {
        return this.http.get(this.url + path, this.standardHeaders()).map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
    }
```

> path = endpoint

Comment: And what is the output of `console.log(response)`?

Comment: I have not yet executed the request because the backend api is not 100% complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, it was only to change the request of:

```
users: User;

this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
          response => {
            if (!response) {
              console.log(Error)
            } else {
              this.users = response
            }
          })
```

for:

```
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(
      response => {
        if (!response) {
          console.log(Error)
        } else {
          console.log(response)
          let users : User[] = response
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your code, How I usually perfrom request like that is with HttpClient using generic get

```
public get(id: number): Observable<className> {
  return this._http.get<className>(`${this._baseUrl}/${id}`);
}
```

and then use like this

```
this.service.get(id).subscribe(x => this.myClass = x);
```

but you are using service, not HttpClient, and you do not specify your return...

Does your `getUsers()` function returns 1 or manu users? 
if you return a list, you should simply change your request variable to `users: User[];`

Comment: He is returning a list. But when I make the change you suggested, the error changes to: Type 'Promise<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'User[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Comment: I added the service in question.